# How to implement the limits of a battery storage when fully charged in a pyomo energy optimizsation problem?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, battery, energy

I'm currently setting up an energy optimization problem with pyomo. Just to give a bit of context: my idea is to minimize overall costs in stand-alone-grids through time-of-use tariffs.

At the moment I'm stuck with implementing a battery storage in my code. My problem is that the battery has a fixed capacity and when I produce more excess solar energy than there is storage in my battery left I run into an issue with my optimization problem because it gets unfeasible.

My approach is to set up two conditions for each time step of my problem:

1. when the excess solar power doesn't exceed the available battery storage: charge battery with the full excess solar energy
2. when the excess solar power exceeds the available battery storage: fully charge the battery

I tried implementing two binary variables y and x. But I don't really understand how to get this done right. Or is this only achievable via disjuncts in pyomo? Because that's a topic I didn't really understand using yet in pyomo...

```
P_Bat = 0.75  # Maximum charge/discharge amount per time step
E_Bat = 1.2  # 1.2 kWh battery capacity
SOC_min = 0.4
SOC_max = 1
bat_0 = E_Bat * SOC_max

...

m.p1 = Var(m.T, domain=NonNegativeReals) 
m.bat = Var(m.T, domain=NonNegativeReals, bounds=(SOC_min * E_Bat, SOC_max * E_Bat)) # Energy in battery for each time step
m.charge = Var(m.T, domain=NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, P_Bat))
m.discharge = Var(m.T, domain=NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, P_Bat))
m.y = Var(m.T, within=Binary)
m.x = Var(m.T, within=Binary)

...

def energy_bat_rule(m, t):
    if t == m.T.first():
        return m.bat[t] == bat_0 + m.charge[t] - m.discharge[t]
    return m.bat[t] == m.bat[t-1] + m.charge[t] - m.discharge[t]
m.Energy_Bat = Constraint(m.T, rule=energy_bat_rule)

def charge_bat_rule(m, t):
    return m.charge[t] == (zeitwerte.at[t, "Solarleistung[kW]"] - m.p1[t]) * m.y[t] + (E_Bat - m.bat[t]) * m.x[t]
m.Charge_Bat = Constraint(m.T, rule=charge_bat_rule)
```